# how to make encryption hill cipher array to have dimension like original array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, encryption

hello i'm beginner and still learning python, I tried encrypting the image using hill cipher with this code :

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

key = np.array([[3, 10, 20],[20, 9, 17],[9, 4, 17]]) #hillcipherkey
key_rows = key.shape[0] 
key_col = key.shape[1]

img = Image.open('50G.png')    #image grayscale 50x50
imgarr = np.array(img)         #original array
flat = imgarr.flatten()

ak = []                      
if len(ak)%key_rows !=0:
        for i in range(0, len(ak)):
                ak.append(ak[i])
                if len(ak)%key_rows == 0:
                        break

ak = np.array(flat)                           
img_len = ak.shape[0]         
ak.resize(int(img_len/key_rows), key_rows)

enc = np.matmul(ak, key)         #encryption process            
enc = np.remainder(enc, 256)

img2 = Image.fromarray(enc.astype('uint8'))
img2.show()
```

and this works, but the result of encryption like this :[Enc.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99D0O.png),
my question is how to make the encryption array have dimensions like the [OriginalImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E88hr.png)?

I tried adding the code as below:

```
shape = imgarr.shape 
enc1 = np.array(enc)
flat_enc = enc.ravel()
arr2 = np.asarray(flat_enc).reshape(shape)
img2 = Image.fromarray(arr2.astype('uint8'))
img2.show()
```

It shows me the following error

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4998 into shape (50,50,2)

Comment: Hint: your array is not correctly padded; `len(ak)` is zero so the `for i in range(0, len(ak))` loop does not run at all.

Answer (score 0):

A hill cipher requires encrypting in blocks of 3, but your input is of length 5000 and thus can't be evenly divided by 3.

Consider instead using a slightly larger image (e.g. 51x51), padding the input properly (your `if len(ak)%key_rows !=0:` loop doesn't do anything), or encrypting RGB images (which will naturally have a size divisible by 3).